# Allow CORS on Nginx to work with AngularJS HTTP GET

Tags: angularjs, http, nginx, cors

I keep getting this error in my console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://d.biossusa.com/api/distributor?key=****. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

I know that I have a CORS issue. I am trying to fix it. Please see my steps below.

---

### First tries

I've tried adding the config on my front-end side.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <p>Today's welcome message is:</p>
  <h1>{{myData}}</h1>

</div>

<script>

  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

  app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
  }

  ]);

  app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://d.biossusa.com/api/distributor?key=****")
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
    });
});


</script>
```

---

I've tried adding the config on my back-end service side on my Nginx Configs.

I found this link on Nginx site = https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html

I've add that in my nginx config like this.

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name d.biossusa.com;
    root /home/forge/d.biossusa.com/distributor-application/laravel/public;

    # Enable this line for debugging to see which php.ini get use ... $php --ini
    # root /home/forge/d.biossusa.com/public;


    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    # ssl_certificate;
    # ssl_certificate_key;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            #
            # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
            #
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
            #
            # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
            #
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
            return 204;
         }


         if ($request_method = 'POST') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
         }


         if ($request_method = 'GET') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
         }


    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/d.biossusa.com-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {

        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
       fastcgi_send_timeout 600;
       fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
       fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;

    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

}
```

I don't know what else I could do to get rid of this error.

---

## 2nd Try

Updated Nginx Settings based on @Yaser Answer:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name d.biossusa.com;
    root /home/forge/d.biossusa.com/distributor-application/laravel/public;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
       set $cors '';
       if ($http_origin ~ '^http?://(www\.d.biossusa\.com)') {
               set $cors 'true';
       }

       if ($cors = 'true') {
               add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin" always;
               add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS' always;
       }
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/d.biossusa.com-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {

        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
       fastcgi_send_timeout 600;
       fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
       fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;

    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

}
```

**Result :**

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://d.biossusa.com/api/distributor?key=****. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.`

---

## 3rd Try

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name d.biossusa.com;
    root /home/forge/d.biossusa.com/distributor-application/laravel/public;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {

       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

       set $cors '';
       if ($http_origin ~ '^http?://(www\.d.biossusa\.com)') {
               set $cors 'true';
       }

       if ($cors = 'true') {
               add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin" always;
               add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS' always;
       }
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/d.biossusa.com-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {

        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
       fastcgi_send_timeout 600;
       fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
       fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;

    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

}
```

**Result**

`**XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://d.biossusa.com/api/distributor?key=****. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.**`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you can't assign CORS permission from Angular, or generally on client side.

Then you don't have to repeat that line for every request type, simply put it the in root of your config file:

```
server {


    listen 8080;

    location / {

        if ($http_origin ~* (http:\/\/d\.biossusa\.com\S*)$) {
            set $cors "true";
        }

        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            set $cors "${cors}options";
        }

        if ($request_method = 'GET') {
            set $cors "${cors}get";
        }
        if ($request_method = 'POST') {
            set $cors "${cors}post";
        }

        if ($cors = "trueget") {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        }

        if ($cors = "truepost") {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        }

        if ($cors = "trueoptions") {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Content-Type,Accept,Origin,User-Agent,DNT,Cache-Control,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since';
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
            return 204;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried adding your suggestion into my nginx config. Restart my server. Refresh my page. I got this new error now on my console. `GET http://d.biossusa.com/api/distributor?key=bunlongheng net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Comment: I beleive you're close.

Comment: Keep in mind that I used to have this settings in my nginx setting :     location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

Comment: Now that I've added your, what should I do with my old settings ?

Comment: you don't need those anymore, and origin is pointing to a domain not the whole url @ihue, and to be honest haven't seen connection refuse for this setting either. The point is you cannot use whildcard for CORS

Comment: Let me remove those, and see what will happen.

Comment: Removing that line leading my end point to 404. See the my updated config and result ...

Comment: you don't need to remove your whole location / content, just the CORS bit you added to your existing config @ihue

Comment: Can you please show my entire `nginx.conf` as part of your answer ? I just want to test it.

Comment: I've added it back in. I got new error now. I think we're close. `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://d.biossusa.com/api/distributor?key=bunlongheng. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: With your update, I got : `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://d.biossusa.com/api/distributor?key=bunlongheng. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.`

Comment: #weird running out of ideas, those two are the working version for me and one of the github repos

Comment: Please let me know, if you have any other suggestion. Your suggestion of 3rd try is the best, maybe you should include that one in your answer in stead. I can close this post up and accept your answer. :D